# NW.js app can't connect to specific web domain and that happens only on one single laptop

Tags: node-webkit

After thinking about this for 2 weeks, I have to ask this question.

I've created a NW.js app that works smoothly and nice on 7 different laptops and PCs. The app shows html videos and contains a bunch of javascripts, I've got deloped since 2 years. Alls this works fine on every laptop/PC.

Here comes the problem:

On one laptop the app works, too, but the app isn't able neither to show HTML frame contents nor to execute js scripts from a specific web domain. This only occurs with a specific domain (that I'm the owner of).

The strange thing is, that this happens only on one laptop.

The laptop uses the same internet connection as some other devices. I reinstalled the app, deleted all subfolders from the app folder, but the error is back. In the frame I see the silly message, that the website is down or moved.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a system-wide proxy configured or possibly some AV software installed on that laptop is blocking that site. Attempt to access the same URL through another browser (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, etc.) to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to your hosts file.

- `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

That is a plain text file without an extension. You can put URL's or IP addresses in it and it will block any access to them globally on the computer.

Though Sysrage is probably right, it's more likely that you just have some AV/firewall/security software blocking stuff it shouldn't (happens all the time, they can be "over protective" sometimes)

If it is something related to your NW.js install, and it isn't happening on other machines (so you know your app code is correct), then you could try deleting the app data folder for you app. To find it's location on the computer run `console.log(nw.App.dataPath)`. It should be something like:

- `C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\AppData\Local\YOUR APP NAME`

You can just delete the whole folder (make sure your app isn't running first). Then the next time you open your app it will recreate that folder (it's a chromium thing). Things like saved passwords or dev tool customization or spellcheck dictionary modifications are stored in there. So maybe there's just something funky that needs cleared out.